# Store division calculation results in array

Tags: php

I have the following simple division calculation in my script:

```
<?php

$total = 1001;
$people = 5;

$division= $total / $people;

echo "division = ".$division;

?>
```

This outputs `division = 200.2`.

Is it possible to instead store it like the following?

```
$division[0] = 200;
$division[1] = 200;
$division[2] = 200;
$division[3] = 200;
$division[4] = 201;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// initital conditions
$total = 1001;
$people = 5;

// count what is the minimal value, that all the results will have
$value = floor($total / $people);
$result = array_fill(0, $people, $value);

// distribute missing "+1"s as needed in the result
$overheads = $total - $value * $people;
for ($i = 0; $i < $overheads; $i++)
    $result[$i]++;

// voila...
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Hi Roman. Many thanks for this. I am just giving this a try right now and will report back asap :)

Comment: Quick follow-up, if you can still assist, instead of `var_dump`, is it possible to echo out each value during the loop? So it would echo `1`,`200`,`200`,`200`,`200`. How do I do this?

Comment: You simply use `foreach` and `echo`, the `$result` is just a regular array of integers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$total = 1001;
$people = 5;
$division = array();
$extra = $total % $people; // Stores the extra number i.e 1
$i = 1;
while ($i <= $people) {
    /* For the last array element, add the extra number */
    if ($i == $people) {  
        $division[] = floor($total/$people) + $extra;
    } else {
        $division[] = floor($total/$people);
    }   
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$total = 1001;
$people = 5;
$division = [];
$difference = intval($total%100);
for($i =0 ; $i < $people; $i++){
    $division[] = ($i == $people - 1) ? (intval($total/ $people) + $difference) : intval($total/ $people);
}
print_r($division);
die;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$total = 1001;
$people = 5;

$division = array();

$division[] = round($total / $people);

echo "division = ".$division[0];
?>
```

This array object will gives you value which was stored and retrieved from array..